# Check if persistent cookie was used in federated authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have searched for it a lot and still have no answer. Can someone please tell me is it possible to tell if a persistent cookie was used in the authentication. Reading all the properties of FederatedAuthentication and the Request object I cannot find a place which specifies this. The cookies and their values are coming out the same .

Thanks

Comment: have you applied .IsPersistent check for the cookie?

Comment: Where is this property located.

Comment: FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.ContextSessionSecurityToken.IsPersistent this comes out false even though I have it stored as persistent cookie.